# autoit: Detecting window screen resolution in an If statement

Tags: autoit

I am using Autoit for a bot that I am making and trying to detect the clients screen resolution first before launching the game. I am making the bot to run at a specific screen size so I want to make sure the client runs it at that size before launching my bot. I have so far

```
; Retrieve the client area of the window.
  $aClientSize = WinGetClientSize("clientWindow")
  If Not ($aClientSize[0] = 1024 & $aClientSize[1] = 768) Then
     WinClose("clientWindow")
     MsgBox(0,"Resolution","Please change your screen resolution in game to 1024x768 in order for this bot to work. Go To Game Menu > Options > Graphics and change it to 1024x768 Then run it again.")
     Exit
  EndIf
```

But no matter what it executes this script so whether it is set at the right resolution or not. Am I running my If Statement incorrectly?

Comment: The logical concatenation in AutoIt is `And`, not `&`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the desktop resolution then there are macros for that purpose: [@DesktopWidth and @DesktopHeight](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm).

However, your code is not working because of a syntax error. Look again at what you are doing with the If test - the `&` operator is for string concatenation! You were looking for `And`.

That means your code is being evaluated something like `$a[0] = ((1024 & $a[1]) = 768)`, so whatever the case, you are comparing `$a[0]` to a boolean, which has to be false (there is no string such that "1024" & string = "768").